# How to check if css_selector currently exist in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I'm having a struggle making a code having a loop, and sometimes it give me an error so I have to exit the site and reenter, so I want a code that checks if the error is there(the css_selector exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Try` and `Except` can be used to check whether element exist or not

Create some module like `common.py` and place the method or you can write it in same file. depend on you

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


def is_element_exist(driver, locator):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(locator)
        return True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
```

Now call it from where you require to check whether element exist or not

```
if is_element_exist(driver, 'css_locator'):
    print('element exist')
else:
    print("element doesn't exist")
```